# How to fix my index.html + bootstrap4

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

> ```
>     *Whenever I reload the page the default bootstrap navbar style appears 
>  before my overridden styles apply 
>  Please any help
> ```
>
> - Whenever I reload the page the default bootstrap navbar style appears 
>        before my overridden styles apply 
>        Please any help w

ill be welcome
    Using bootstrap 4 Here my index.html file with custum CSS bellow*

> Head

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/75528e6985.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

> Style

```
.selector-for-some-widget {
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }

    body {
        background: #e9ebee;
    }

    .logo {
        background-color: rgba(18, 101, 204, 0.82);
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        padding-left: 7px;
        padding-right: 7px;
        font-size: 29px;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 11px;
    }

    a .navbar-brand {
        color: #baccce!important;
    }

    .pull-right {
        margin-right: 150px;
    }

    .bookUs-btn {
        color: #5d85b7;
        margin: -56px 88% 29px;
        border-color: #5d85b7;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .bookUs-btn:hover {
        background-color: #5d85b7;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        margin-right: 20%!important;
    }
```

> Nav

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-light bg-faded" style="background: #172944;" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2">
  &#9776;
</button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <span class="logo">K
    </span>
    OMRIHE
  </a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">PORTFOLIO 
        <span class="sr-only">(current)
        </span>
      </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOG
      </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT ME
      </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <span class="">
    <button class=" btn btn-primary-outline bookUs-btn">
      <i class="fa fa-phone-square">
      </i> Contact Me
    </button>
  </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap need jquery tether.js and boostrap.min.js

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start